# How to add “ ?&max-results= ” after the /search/label/LABEL_NAME in blogger use javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

I want to change all the labels links and have a specific number to access it in blogger using JavaScript automatically 
An illustrative example

`../search/label/Label_name` and add `max-results=7` after `"label name"`

how i can do it .. i want help and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick. If you have further questions feel free to ask them :)

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll("a");

x.forEach(function(element){
  var link = element.href;
  console.log(link)
  element.href = link + "?max-results=7";
  console.log(element.href);
});
```

```html
<a href="../search/label/Label_name">Example link</a>
```